# childview in scrollview click delay after scroll

Tags: android, webview, scrollview

I have a webview inside a scrollview with javascript listening click event.
It is no problem to listen it in normal case but cannot be listen just after scroll. I need to have a first click to stop the scroll and click one or two times to trigger the click event. Or wait a while until the scrollbar fade out.

I have done a research and know it is normal behavior of scrollview. I have try to set a ontouchlistener on webview to requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true) but just make it cannot able to scroll anymore. Is it there are any approach to cancel the scrolling and perform a click at the same time with no delay in a scrollview?

Comment: webview has its own scrollview then why should you need to put it in scrollview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have solved it by reading the document. I just put `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` 
in the main child view of scrollview and then solve my problem.

For Gopal Singh Sirvi asking, I think you need to put a webview in a scrollview in some cases. Let say the data of one section contains html code. I guess the content page of gmail is also like this. (After open show layout bounds, the content seems inside a webview but others not)

Hope this help!